# If Statement that checks something's background color?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a small application that randomizes a background color (red, green or blue) and sets them for 9 backgrounds.

The app also randomizes a color an user has to click to get a point.
My question is, is there any way in Java in AndroidStudio that I can make an if statement that somehow takes the value of an object's background color?

```
if ( color_user_has_to_pick == background_color) {
point++
}
else {
nothing }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following way to get the background color of a view and the checking if that matches with user picked color

```
ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
if(someColorId == colorId) {
   //....
}
```

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I needed!
But what the colorId will be? A hex value that matches the .getBackground color?

Comment: Because I have an int "cel" that 
if the_color_you_have_to_pick is red then cel = 1
if -||- is blue then cel = 2
if -||- is green then cel = 3

Answer (score 0):

If there's a set number of background colors, I would just compare the resource ids since it's pretty convenient:

`if (R.id.blue === ((ColorDrawable) view.getBackground()).getColor()) {
   // Your logic
}`

But, as an alternative you could disregard the colour comparison and just create a data structure to hold the current values of the game (the state), assign identifiers to these colour values and compare said identifiers.